# Display dynamic images in a flash file

Tags: c#, flash

I bought a website template that has a scrolling photo gallery.  As it came, the images are static in the fla file itself.  I would like to edit the fla and load images dynamically.  Ideally from MSSQL.  I'm using VS2010, C# webforms, and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Are there any code snippets or tutorials or general guidance on how to do this?  I do have a CS3 disc with Flash on it I can use for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Loader + URLRequest, something like: (untested code)

```
var imgLoader:Loader = new Loader();
imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageHasBeenLoaded);
imgLoader.load(new URLRequest("imagePath/from/database.jpg"));

public function imageHasBeenLoaded(e:Event) {     
      //Get the loaded bitmap image, do what you want with it from here.
      var img:Bitmap = Bitmap(e.target.content); 
}
```

Of course you would also want to feed the file paths to flash, either by FlashVars or by hitting a web service type of page (or xml file) via a Flash URLLoader + URLRequest. I prefer an xml file myself.

Comment: I'm pretty much a newbie to this so I will need to find some tutorials and get up to speed.  I have no idea if your answer is correct or not so I'll have to come back to it.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, we are here to help :)